# How does Crossfilter prevent the selected chart from rerendering?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm working off of a modified version of the Crossfilter code here: http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

I'm trying to understand how this implementation prevents the currently selected chart from re-rendering. In my modified version, all charts re-render on selection, leading to some strange results.

Comment: You'll have to give more information about your code and what you've changed (preferably, as a simplified working example) if you want anyone else to be able to figure out what's going wrong.  Generally, things don't re-render without an event or timer triggering a redraw.

Comment: The re-rendering occurs when I'm dragging the brush, with the issue being that it also affects the chart I'm brushing.

I've removed the flightList function, added some variables and swapped out the dataset (to unrelated data). That said, I haven't made any other considerable changes to the functionality that should prevent a flag from being triggered, for example. So I'm trying to understand how this occurs in the example, since the structure is for the most part unchanged.

Interestingly, I noticed that after the brush crosses a certain 'hour', the rendering function ceases to be called.